# How to find items and feats based on a specific requirement like "CON enhancement"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, online-resources

I am looking for a database or a filterable list online where I can find out specific bonuses on abilities.

My current specific problem is, that my character has lousy CON stats, and I'd like to improve these. It would be great to find some on-line database, a filterable/searchable list based on things like "+CON", "+INT", "+Perception" etc.
Even a huge CSV file containing all items, spells etc. and having these columns would be a great help.

The format might look something like this:

```
Item                   Price   STR DEX CON ... AC ...
Ring of Protection      2000g  N   N   N   ... Y  ...
Belt of Physical Might 10000g  Y   Y   Y   ... N  ...
...
```

Until now I only found a table with all magic items on the [pathfindercommunity web site](http://www.pathfindercommunity.net/home/databases/magic-items) containing these columns: Name, Aura, CL, Slot, Price, Weight, Description, Requirements, Cost, Group, Source, AL, Int, Wis, Cha, Ego, Communication, Senses, Powers, MagicItems, FullText, Destruction, MinorArtifactFlag, MajorArtifactFlag, Abjuration, Conjuration, Divination, Enchantment, Evocation, Necromancy, Transmutation, AuraStrength, WeightValue, PriceValue, CostValue, Languages, BaseItem, LinkText, id, Mythic, LegendaryWeapon, Illusion, Universal

**Edit**: I found some interesting info in one of [PCGen](http://pcgen.org/)'s .lst [files](http://pcgen.org/autobuilds/pcgen-docs/index.html): ultimate_equipment/ue_equip_magic_items.lst:

```
Belt of Mighty Constitution +2 [...] BONUS:STAT|CON|2|TYPE=Enhancement
```

I think, I'll parse these files with a little script; that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use only the standard magic itens.

Magic itens, as all rules on Pathfinder, are guidelines, not something written on stone. You can always create your own magic itens, according to your needs. If you want to go that way, just check a similar item that does what you want (Let's imagine a Gloves of Giant Might, +4 STR) and change the bonuses to something else.

That's said:

[This page](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/wondrousItems.html) contains a bunch of core pathfinder magic itens. While it is not on a CSV or database format, you can simply use Ctrl+F and search for Constitution (or any other score) to find what you are looking for.

My suggestion, however, is using a bit of GM Trickery to solve this issue. If you want to raise the Con value of a single character:

- Organize an encounter where the players find a helpful druid, wich uses some "experimental magic". Show them some random magic spells, completly different from anything they know - things like Explosive Butterflies of Doom or Homing Hummingbird (Like a Magic Missile, but with force-birds).
- Keep the druid around and give the players a small quest, to help him do some stuff. Make the druid promise some nice, but exclusive, consumables, like "Potion: Mass Cure Moderate Wounds" - you drink, all the party gets healed.
- When the players are almost going away, after saying goodbye to this crazy druid, make something appear from nowhere, like a huge ogre. This ogre hit the Druid with his club, making him fly away inconcious, leaving the party to face it alone.
- Kill the Low-Con character. Use hidden combatants if needed - a Wizard using Save-Or-Die, con-based spells would be nice.
- When the party kills the Ogre, the Wizard runs away.
- The druid wakes up, and *Reincarnate* the fallen combatants. This reincarnation, however, as his other spells, is experimental and thus could have "unexpected effects". Use this to change his values around and raise his Con, while keeping his appearence.

It will depends on your party, but it could solve your issue. I used something similar trying to solve a Low-Int issue, where the druid, after the reincarnation, said that the "low-int" was because of a crayon stuck on the brain of the character, but the reincarnation gave him a Crayon-less skull.

We got a bunch of laughs, the players got really happy, and everything went fine!

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/)
2. Search on "bonus to Constitution"
3. In the faceted navigation at the top choose "Magic Items"
4. The aristocrats!

[Here's a link](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=belt%20of#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=bonus%20to%20Constitution&gsc.sort=&gsc.ref=more%3Amagic_items) I think will work for other people...

It's not perfect, there's some items you will need to discard ("This doesn't provide a bonus to Constitution" is a hit) but should get you all your likely options.

Comment: confirming that the link works for other people.

Comment: it's important to add the quotation marks in the search field, otherwise you get way too many results. nevertheless it's a good workaround.